# JavaScript - Needs to click twice to edit input and weird SW error when doing so (IE 11 only)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Input needs to be clicked twice to be editable. On first click I get this weird error from Service Worker `Object 'caches' is undefined`. This error didn't shows up until I click any of the inputs. When the input is blurred this error shows once more.

Demo: https://softec.honzachalupa.cz/ (username: `9999`, password: `9.9.9999`)

[image: Bug in IE's console.]

Render method of my input component:

```js
...
render() {
        const { id, additionalStyle } = this.props;
        const { value, displayValue, inputState, units, unitsSymbol, inputWidth, inputContainerWidth, isReadOnly, limitedFeatures } = this.state;

        const type = (inputState === 'edit') ? 'number' : 'text';
        const valueToBeDisplayed = (inputState === 'edit' || limitedFeatures) ? value : displayValue;

        return (
            <div className={classNames({ readonly: isReadOnly }, additionalStyle)} style={{ minWidth: `${inputContainerWidth}rem`, width: `${inputContainerWidth}rem` }}>
                {!isReadOnly &&
                    <img style={{ display: `${inputState === 'edit' ? 'none' : ''}` }} src={EditIcon} alt="" />
                }
                <input style={{ width: `${inputWidth}rem` }} name={id} type={type} value={valueToBeDisplayed} pattern="[0-9,.]*" readOnly={isReadOnly} autoComplete="off" ref={(input) => { this.input = input; }} onFocus={this.handleFocus} onBlur={this.handleBlur} onKeyDown={(e) => this.handleKeyDown(e, units)} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <p className="units" onClick={() => { this.input.focus(); }}>{unitsSymbol}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Please share the relevant part of your code with us, particularly the part where you get the error.

Comment: @LajosArpad I've added it but it really doesn't matters. When I add a blank <input ... /> anywhere in my app it has the same weird behavior. Triggered function like `onFocus` doesn't affect this.

Comment: That's the most important thing. You need to look at the code part where the error occurs in order to fix it. I do not see any usages of a variable called caches in the code you have given, yet the problem is that this specific variable is not defined.

Comment: @LajosArpad This `caches` variable is used in service-worker, which is placed in different file and my input has no dependency on it - that's why I called it a weird behavior. Please try the demo.

Comment: Your problem does not reproduce for me. It is possible that your code is cached. Please try to reproduce your problem in incognito mode.

Comment: @LajosArpad I can reproduce it on all of my Windows devices using both normal and incognito modes (on top of that a removed browser's data for a few times).

Comment: @Jan Chalupa, I try to login to your site with the above mentioned username and password to check for the issue but it shows incorrect username and password error. Can you please try to check whether it is valid credentials or not?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT You are right. Please try 9999/9.9.9999. Thank you.

Comment: If you go to the line where error get occur than you will notice that it is using '=> ' which is not supported in IE. So are you using any babel for it? If no than you can try to check it by adding babel. you can also check whether any other thing is not supported with IE and replace it.